# What are the best practices for storing .proto files and corresponding generated java code?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

We have a gradle built project that makes use of protobuf-generated Java classes. What are some best practices around storing and using this code? Some ideas that we've had:

1. Store any generated code in a separate package and re-generate each time using the gradle build script.
2. Check in the generated code and rely on it directly, only re-generate it when changes to the proto file is made
3. Create a separate library (new project) that stores all proto and generated files and introduce a dependency between the current project and the new library.

From scouring some resources, we've seen that checking in generated files is usually avoided, so solution #2 would be out. What are other best practices or solutions that can be recommended?

Comment: Regenerating protos from source every time is generally best.